# Displaying Arrays in PHP using Object Oriented Programming

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm experimenting with PHP and object oriented programming in PHP. When I try to run the following `displayArray` function, it does not display the line at all. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
class Student
{
    var $name;
    var $arr;

    function Student()
    {
        $this->name = "bob";
        $this->addnametostring("Hello there ");
        $this->arr = array();

        for($i=0; $i<30; $i++) {
            $arr[$i] = rand(0,100);
        }
    }

    function addnametostring($s)
    {
        $s.= " " . $this->name;
        echo "$s <br>";
    }

    function displayArray($amt)
    {
        foreach($this->arr as $key) { 
        //why is this not working
        echo "<br>hello: ".$key;
    }
}
```

}

```
$student = new Student;
echo "<br>";
$student->displayArray(20);

?>
```

Comment: @kevinabelita Please do not suggest edits which substantially change the op's code. Formatting edits are good, but edits which change the code itself are not. [Your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4688940) removed one of the op's closing braces.

Comment: Good catch on the closing brace, while editing, I may have missed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Out of topic, But you OOPS style is more like php-4 style OOPS. I would suggest to use private instead of var, Also prefix methods with public/protected/private for better understand OOPS in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
   $arr[$i] = rand(0,100);
}
```

to

```
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
   $this->arr[$i] = rand(0,100);
}
```

EDIT: Did not notice you are missing your constructor, so your entire class should look like this

```
class Student(){

    var $name;
    var $arr;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = "bob";
        $this->addnametostring("Hello there ");
        $this->arr = array();

        for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
            $this->arr[$i] = rand(0,100);
        }

    }

    function addnametostring($s){
        $s.= " " . $this->name;
        echo "$s <br>";
    }

    function displayArray($amt){
        foreach($this->arr as $key){
            //why is this not working
            echo "<br>hello: ".$key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in php constructer is as follow

```
function __construct(){
//some code
}
```

so you are not calling student function.

Comment: His example of constructor is valid for PHP. PHP allow both __construct and <className> methods as constructor. Only namespaced class (> 5.3.3) treat only __construct as constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [constructor](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/oop-constructor-destructor) to easily assign the array when you first call the class.

```
<?php
class Student
{
    public $name;
    public $arr;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = "bob";
        $this->addnametostring("Hello there ");
        $this->arr = array();

        for($i=0; $i<30; $i++) {
            $this -> arr[$i] = rand(0,100);
        }
    }

    function addnametostring($s)
    {
        $s.= " " . $this->name;
        echo "$s <br>";
    }

    function displayArray()
    {
        foreach($this->arr as $key) { 
            //why is this not working
            echo "<br>hello: ".$key;
        }
    }
}
```

Then,

```
$student = new Student;
echo "<br>";
$student-> displayArray();
```

I'm not sure why you had `$amt` variable.

Thanks.